# VueJS 2.0 server-side rendering: How to get data only once using preFetch and beforeRouteEnter?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js, server-side-rendering

To test VueJS server sider rendering, i'm trying to figure some things out. I've used the latest [VueJS Hackernews 2.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0) as my boilerplate for this project.

Currently i'm stuck with this:

The server prefetches data using `preFetch`. All good.
When a user routes to this component, the same function gets called inside the `beforeRouteEnter` function. All good.

However, when the user loads it for the first time, the `preFetchData` function gets called 2 times. Once in `preFetch` and once in `beforeRouteEnter`.

This makes sense, because that's just how the Vue Router works. `preFetch` is run on the server and as soon as Vue renders in the client, the `beforeRouteEnter` gets called.

But, i don't want Vue to do this 2 times on the first load, because the data is already in the store from the server side rendering function `preFetch`.

I can't check if the data is already in the store, because i want that component to always make the API call on `beforeRouteEnter`. Just not when it renders for the first time when it comes from the server.

How to get the data only once in this context?

```js
  <template>
    <div class="test">
        <h1>Test</h1>
      <div v-for="item in items">
        {{ item.title }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
  import store from '../store'

  function preFetchData (store) {
    return store.dispatch('GET_ITEMS')
  }

  export default {
    beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
      // We only want to use this when on the client, not the server
      // On the server we have preFetch
      if (process.env.VUE_ENV === 'client') {
        console.log('beforeRouterEnter, only on client')
        preFetchData(store)
        next()
      } else {
        // We are on the server, just pass it
        next()
      }
    },
    name: 'test',
    computed: {
      items () {
        return this.$store.state.items
      }
    },
    preFetch: preFetchData // Only on server
  }
  </script>

  <style lang="scss">
  .test {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 40px;

    div {
      border-bottom: 1px red solid;
    }
  }
  </style>
```

In the above: the API call is done in the `store.dispatch('GET_ITEMS')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've already figured something out. I'll check where the user comes from with `from.name`. If this is `null`, it means the user loads the page for the first time because i name all my routes. So we then know we are serving the server rendered HTML:

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) { 
    if (from.name && process.env.VUE_ENV === 'client') {
      preFetchData(store).then(data => {
        next(vm => {
          // do something
        })
      })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also vue to check if you are on the server or not.

```
this.$isServer
```

or

```
Vue.prototype.$isServer
```

Only have your beforeRouteEnter prefetch be called if you are local.

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    // We only want to use this when on the client, not the server
    // On the server we have preFetch
    if (!this.$isServer) {
        console.log('beforeRouterEnter, only on client')
        preFetchData(store)
        next()
    } else {
        // We are on the server, just pass it
        next()
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But unfortunately that doesn't work. It is correct it is not running that part on the server using your suggestion. But after the server outputted it, Vue will go over it, and then we are on the client again. So beforeRouteEnter also get's called there on first load...

Answer (score 0):

What you could do it set a variable on the store saying the data for this page was already loaded. Read that variable to see if you should call the ajax request.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion again! but i've tried something else. See the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm just checking if window object is defined in the `created` method of the component:

```
created () {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    // we're in server side
  } else {
    // we're in the client
  }
}
```